# ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of SUM | MEAN

Tags: arcpy, error-000800

I've written following code to make a summary list of no of features having same "ID" values so that I can later remove duplicate "ID" values from them if any.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
for layer in layers:
    lyr = layer
    desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
    path1 = str(desc.path) + r"\outstat.dbf"

    env.workspace = desc.path
    arcpy.Statistics_analysis(lyr, path1, ["SUM"], "ID")
```

However this script gives error 000800 whenever I run it.
Exact error message is:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 11, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 1160, in Statistics     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of SUM | MEAN | MIN | MAX | RANGE | STD | COUNT | FIRST | LAST.
```

How can I resolve the error I am making?

There is only one layer in the mxd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
for layer in layers:
   lyr = layer
   desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
   path1 = str(desc.path) + r"\outstat.dbf"

   env.workspace = desc.path
   arcpy.Statistics_analysis(lyr, path1, [["ID","COUNT"]], "ID")
```